# Android Update Sharepoint List Item

Tags: android, sharepoint

Looking for any direction in how to update an item in a Sharepoint list from an Android application.  I have seen several mentions of SOAP and Web Services but nothing that shows a simple example of updating a Sharepoint list item from android or the steps involved.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **(1)** Do you know how to call any SOAP Web Service method from an Android device? **(2)** SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Comment: **(1)** Then investigate the topic of calling SOAP methods from Android first - it has been discussed on SO before. **(2)** Unfortunately SharePoint 2007 does not have a REST interface. Is creating a custom, RESTful Web Service an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, Android development is actually Java development. Hence you could look at this article about [creating list items in Java](http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/creating-sharepoint-list-items-with-java-tutorial/).

Comment: Nope,you can try to use REST api to access List of SharePoint 2010